# Insert multiple lines between a pattern at some specific position using sed

Tags: python, regex, sed

I am working on a python module with so many functions. I want to insert few lines in a particular function at some specific position. Suppose this is the code:

```
def abc():

    #few lines of code
    context =  {}
    return context

def xyz():

    #few lines of code
    context = {}
    return context
```

Now I want to add "This is new line" just before context but only in function xyz:

```
def abc():

    #few lines of code
    context =  {}
    return context

def xyz():

    #few lines of code
    This is new line
    context = {}
    return context
```

How can I do this using sed? Also the function where new line has to be added can be anywhere, need not be at the start or at the end.

Comment: Why "using sed" if you can use Python for that? 8-)

Comment: @Blotosmetek Actually I am creating a patch which can be applied to any version of that python module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed '/^def xyz/,/^[[:space:]]*context/{s/^\([[:space:]]*\)context/\1This is new line\n&/;}' file
```

**Explanations:**

- `/^def xyz/,`: from line starting with `def xyz`
- `/^[[:space:]]*context/`: up to line starting with spaces(or tabs) followed by `context`
- `s/^\([[:space:]]*\)context/\1This is new line\n&/;`: replace spaces/tabs and `context` with captured spaces, followed by the new string followed by a newline(`\n`)

Comment: Could you please explain this? I am new to sed

Comment: I edited my answer. If you want to learn more about sed, I recommend this excellent [Introduction and tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html)

Comment: How "This is new line" follows the same indentation as context ?

Comment: Space/tabs before `context` are captured with `\([[:space:]]*\)` and output in substitution string with `\1`(backreference).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` for this job:

Input file:

```
cat file
def abc():

    #few lines of code
    context =  {}
    return context

def xyz():

    #few lines of code
    context = {}
    return context

def pqr():

    #few lines of code
    context =  {}
    return context
```

And here is awk:

```
awk '/^def /{fnflag = index($0, " xyz()")}
    fnflag && /context = /{print "    This is new line"} 1' file
def abc():

    #few lines of code
    context =  {}
    return context

def xyz():

    #few lines of code
    This is new line
    context = {}
    return context

def pqr():

    #few lines of code
    context =  {}
    return context
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort but for some reasons I have to use sed

Comment: You may get some complex sed script here but bottom line is that `sed` is wrong tool for this job.

Comment: Ok I will look into awk also.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

sed

```
sed -i '
    /def xyz\>/ {
        :A
        n
        /\<context\>/ {
            i\
    This is a new line
            bB
        }
        bA
    }
    :B
' file
```

See [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Programming-Commands.html#Programming-Commands) for documentation about `:` and `b`

I use the word boundary markers `\<` and `\>` to avoid ambiguity for the patterns (i.e. to avoid matching `def xyz123()`)

or ed

```
ed file <<'END'
/def xyz\>
/\<context\>
i
    This is a new line
.
wq
END
```

Comment: Given all that, I'd use `awk` instead

Answer (score 0):

A lazy alternative to the accepted answer

```
sed  '/^def xyz/,/^def/ s/.*context =.*/   This is a new line\n&/'
```